# Rule Based Join in pig script

Tags: apache-pig

I have a rules_table data

### Ruleid,leftColumn,rightColumn

```
1,c1,c1
2,c2,c3
3,c4,c4
```

rules_table contains the column names of left_table and right_table to give hint about the join keys.

### Left_table

Schema : c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9

### Right_table

schema : c1,c2,c3,c4,c10,c12,c13,c14

i need to join the left_table and right_table according to the rules_table applying rules one by one(it should be sequential as the rule_id is the rule priority) . After each rule i need to get a matched_set and unmatched_set. Unmatched_Set data has to flow into next rule and go on like that. Final output will have 2 seperate datasets

- matched_set,rule_id
- unmatched_set

Right now I am using *unix_script* to read the rules table in hive and call the pig-script repeatedly to generate the *matched_set* and *unmatched_set*. But it is taking too much time as the *pig initial set_up* and *store* is taking too much time.

Can any body please suggest an optimal solution to do this in pig_script with single execution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly, but you can generate single pig script that will look somthing like that:

```
LeftTable = load ...;
RightTable = load ...;
joined1 = join LeftTable by c1 full, RightTable by c2;

SPLIT joined1 INTO Matched_rule1_raw IF LeftTable::c1 is not null and   RightTable::c2 is not null, UnMatched_rule1 IF LeftTable::c1 is null or RightTable::c2 is null; 

Matched_rule1 = foreach Matched_rule1_raw generate 1 as rule_id, ..;
```

At the end you can do union matched.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey : But this will be more of a predefined join(Defined before execution) , What i am looking for is a dynamic join according to the data in rules_table , join has to happen one after the other during run time.

Comment: @Jijo Well, you've said you're are already using unix_script to read rules table. You can generate pig script directly  in your unix script. It's not too complex.